# Matching the Same Number of Chars that was Captured by a Previous Group

Tags: regex, expression

Using regular expressions, is it possible to match a number of characters corresponding to the length of a previously captured group ?

I would like to match the following :

```
SomeLengthyPattern :
some_stuff         :
some_other_stuff   :
```

My idea was capturing `SomeLengthyPattern` and then using its length as a base to match `some_stuff` and `some_other_stuff`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly... **Yes!**

> With a handful or regex engines, you can make sure that one token is matched the same number of times as a previous token.

- In .NET, you can do it with balancing groups.
- In PCRE and a few other, you can use what is known on this site as the Qtax trick. The requirement is that a capture Group must be able to contain a back-reference refer to itself.

**Warning!** These techniques are advanced. If you proceed further, your regex skills will improve tremendously.

**Resources**

- .NET: [Using balancing groups to match two tokens the same number of times](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23715855/1078583)
- PCRE: in the same question, scroll up for Casimir's answer (the system does not let me link twice)
- [Capturing Quantifiers and Quantifier Arithmetic](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifier-capture.html)