# Matching a^n b^n c^n (for example “aaabbbccc”) using regular expressions in C#

Tags: c#, regex

You can easily use regex to verify a regular language. My question is can you use it to verify a context-sensitive language? How powerful is the modern regex in the hierarchy?

How would you go about to create a regex that checks for strings that match a^n b^n c^n?

The following cases should match:

```
abc
aabbcc
aaabbbccc
```

The following cases should not match:

```
abbc
aabbc
aabbbccc
```

Comment: Is n known?  Or is it any number as long as the number is the same for all the letters?

Comment: @Robbert sounds like the latter

Comment: Related: [Capturing Quantifiers and Quantifier Arithmetic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23001137/capturing-quantifiers-and-quantifier-arithmetic)

Comment: What's the point? It's not a regular language, regular expressions is the wrong tool for the job.  You might be able to coerce it to work by using nonstandard/ridiculous solutions but again... what's the point...

Comment: @JeffMercado: The point is to determine what’s written in the question, I suppose: *“How powerful is the modern regex in the hierarchy?”*

Comment: @minitech Yes I'm aware of that. Heck, we could probably even use modern engines to (correctly) parse HTML, but it still isn't the right tool for such a task.

Answer (score 13):

.NET provides [balancing groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#balancing_group_definition) that you should be able to use to do this; something like:

```
^(?<n>(?<o>a))*(?<-n>b)*(?<-o>c)*(?(n)(?!))(?(o)(?!))$
```

Increment `n` and `o` for each `a`, decrement `n` for each `b` and then `o` for each `c`, then fail the match (`(?!)`) if either counter is still greater than zero.

Comment: I didn't think it would have been possible to do such a thing!

Comment: @minitech - Congratulations on reaching 100K reputation!