# What is a regular expression that will match a character at certain indexes?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

Is there a single regular expression that will match strings that have the letter "a" or "x" at certain indexes?

For example, the indexes may be

```
0, 3, 6
1, 4, 7
2, 5, 8
```

Possible patterns according to these indexes:

```
"a--a--a--"
"-x--x--x-"
"--a--a--a"
```

Other occurrences of `"a"` or `"x"` are okay. I just want to make sure certain indexes contain `"a"`.

EDIT: This problem is a subproblem of a tic-tac-toe board. I'm to determine if there is a winner by using a regular expression. I don't want the answer to this. I just want a bit of a push to help me move toward the final answer. The above is to help me find a regex that would identify if there is a vertical winner.

Comment: Is it always the same interval between the indexes? All your examples have them separated by 3.

Comment: Yes it is always the same interval between the indexes.

Comment: If you know the indices then why not just check these 3 individual characters using simple `if` condition

Comment: The answer to this question will let me develop a more complicated regex, so I need to know how to do this with a regex

Comment: "*The answer to this question will let me develop a more complicated regex*" this is recipe for [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: To be honest, regular expressions sound like a *terrible* fit for this problem.

Comment: I understand that, but I really just want the solution to this part.

Comment: Please, please, explain us your more complicated problem.

Comment: Edited my question @CasimiretHippolyte

Comment: Ok, I think answers will help you, if you want to go further, you can take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039670/vertical-regex-matching-in-an-ascii-image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
([a-zA-Z])..\1..\1
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xz4JqR/5)

- `([a-zA-Z])` will match and capture any letter in group #`
- Then another 2 instances of same letter at `n+3` and `n+6` positions are matched using back-reference `\1`, where `n` is the first position of letter.

Comment: He said `a` is allowed at other positions, it could be before the first one at the index he cares about. So you shouldn't have `[^a]*` to exclude those.

Comment: I chose this answer because of its flexibility, cuz now I can test for any character(s). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If your tic-tac-toe looks like a 9 chars long string, testing this pattern should suffice to know if there's a vertical line:

```
a..a..a
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `a` appears every 3 characters, `(a..)*` will match those repetitions. Then you just need to precede that with a pattern that matches the required number of characters before it, which is simply `n-1` `.` patterns.

So for the three examples you gave, it's

```
^(a..)*
^.(a..)*
^..(a..)*
```

Comment: Knowing he always matches this on a 9-char string, why not simply `(a..){3}` ?

Comment: I thought he wanted to find the match starting at a specific position.

Comment: You're right, the regex I gave works only for the problem he gave (verticals), but would not work for the diagonals of the tic-tac-toe. Anyways, this matters not : @Casimir et Hippolyte 's answer is right on, and extremely simple.