# Can i match the character directly below another character in a string of arbitrary length?

Tags: regex

Given a string of arbitrary length, a newline and another string of the same length, is it possible to produce regex that will match the character directly below a character on the first line?

For example, what single regex pattern could capture the character below X for all these inputs:

```
........X..  and  .X.........  and  .....X..... etc.
...........       ...........       ...........
```

It seems to me, that you must know the position of X in order to get match the character underneath. Manually i can figure out that the pattern

```
X\.+\n.{8}(.)
```

that captures the character underneath X in this example

```
........X..
...........
```

since i know that X is is the 9th character on the first line. This however doesn't work if X has any other position, which is the core of the problem.

So the question is: Is it possible to create a pattern in regex, that matches the character underneath another character, and what would that look like?

Comment: Realize it is a fallacy to think regex can count _dynamically_. Nothing is farther from the truth.

Comment: IMO, this seems too specific for regex and could be done easier leveraging the indexes of the strings. For example, in c# you could find the `index` of your 'X' and then go to the next line, then pull the character that is `strLine[index]`

Comment: But sure, a regex can be pre-constructed `(?m)^.{15}.+\r?\n^.{15}(.)` where group1 contains said character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you know the length of the first line ahead of time, something like this should work for an `X` in any position:

```regex
/.*?X.{11}(.)/gs
```

Replace `11` with your desired line length.

https://regex101.com/r/HOA9p1/2/

Comment: This is really an elegant solution - had totally forgotten about single-line mode! However, it does not work when the line length is unknown, but perhaps then the problem is better solved using something other than regex as @dvo suggests. Thanks for the answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the length it's possible by a technique introduced in [Vertical Regex Matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039670/vertical-regex-matching-in-an-ascii-image).

```
^(?:.(?=.*\n(\1?.)))*?X.*\n\1?(.)
```

[Here is a demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/L1y8b2/1)

This works in regex flavors supporting *forward references* like PCRE, .NET, Python, Java (not in JS).
Using [possessive](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) `\1?+` it [will even fail](https://regex101.com/r/KJMXCT/2) if the offset of `X` is beyond the end of the line below.

*How it works*: While the outer [`(?:` non-capturing group `)`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) gets [repeated](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), the [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) inside a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is *growing* from itself by adding a character *from the consecutive line* on each repitition until `X` will be matched.  `\1` is a [reference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to what got captured by the *first group* from the consecutive line, where it finally gets pasted. The *second group* shows the character *below* `X`.

---

A variant to replace the *character below* `X` with `Y` by use of another capturing group:
Search for `^((?:.(?=.*\n(\2?.)))*?X.*\n)\2?.` and replace with `$1$2Y` ([regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q0taTV/1)).

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with your exact example then you basically have to build out all of the combinations as regex does not track the position of a match. If you are using a specific programming language then the language may offer a solution but pure regex does not.

```
((?:X\.{10}\n)(\.))|((?:\.X\.{9}\n)(:?\.)(\.))|((?:\.{2}X\.{8}\n)(:?\.{2})(\.))
```

My example only goes up to the third position but you get the idea...

https://regex101.com/r/atVAZK/1/

Comment: When dealing with their exact example, the distance between the X on the first line and the intended match on the second line is always the same. Taking this into account hugely simplifies the regex: https://regex101.com/r/HOA9p1/2/

Comment: @JoshuaWade Wow. You should make that into an answer.

Comment: @JoshuaWade - It doesn't work that way  https://regex101.com/r/HOA9p1/3, the only thing known is the position of X on the first line of dissimilar lines.

Comment: I suppose you can't make the assumption I made based on the wording. I'm going on their example, where all the line lengths are the same. I think this would only matter if they needed to process multiple examples in one go, but I could be missing something.