# How to find a number under a certain word using regex?

Tags: regex

Trying to get the number `811.00` when its placed under the word `Size`.

I know how to get the number when its NEAR some word, like "Jerusalem" in this case.
But here I'm trying to get the number when it's *under* the word `Size`.

```
Property Size
Jerusalem 811.00
A new property agreement
```

Thanks, Couldn't Find any solution for this.

Comment: Please mention tool/lang you're using and show what you have tried yet, it will help others.

Comment: *Related*: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57515015/5527985 - Would be helpful if you provide some more information or even show how you solved it. :)

Answer (score 3):

This can be accomplished by a technique introduced in [vertical regex matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039670/vertical-regex-matching-in-an-ascii-image) and requires a regex flavor with support for [possessive quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) and *forward references* [like PCRE or Java](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref2.html#forward).

I don't know if it's worth the effort but it's certainly an interesting task by use of regex. I found the biggest challenge to keep the start of the number below above words boundaries to the left and right. In the following pattern I tried to only catch full numbers and prevent any partial matching.

```
^(?:.(?=.*\n(\1?+.)))*?(?=Size)(?:\w\B(?=.*\n\1?+(\2?+\D)))*+.*\n\1?+\2?+(?<![\d.])([\d.]+)
```

| regex-part | explained |
| --- | --- |
| `^(?:.(?=.*\n(\1?+.)))*?(?=Size)` | [captures](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) substring from below line [up to](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) above word to `$1` the *first group* is growing at each repetition by one character |
| `(?:\w\B(?=.*\n\1?+(\2?+\D)))*+` | captures any [non-digits](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html#negated) matching above words length to `$2` [`\B` (non word boundary)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541573/what-are-non-word-boundary-in-regex-b-compared-to-word-boundary) prevents skipping over the margin |
| `.*\n\1?+\2?+(?<![\d.])([\d.]+)` | consumes what is captured and capturing the number to `$3` the negative [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) prevents matching numbers partially |

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8ICMXy/4) or a [PHP demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##jZFNa8JAEIbv@yumQciukVXbS/GjS4uU0oMK0pNrS5qOJpBswmaDtkX/erqrldKD6GU/5n3eGWamiIu6Hojp05SQdhuqMlEroBmDrEpNmiiEZRquSEPjCjcwBH/3SkWPUzHkTamo7IqAM8aawkZmyRcyq8q1fPgFnE7ltQjkyFHBMeZCVAyu5vKDLxjdXwHbZX6fkEZpdGlLzYk/1XmB2nyCS02eUVdlmOJtt8s7Hb91Ss/OAnCeuAS5iDlCC9vaMtcYRjE9tHg/A/dg5JsA2OHjxugwMqCq7B01rBMTQ2EH/5aFJootkyzp358edtLa57BnXhnGwKUCwCjOwXucvIxHMLwDjzt1frPgHiSqB1LZiHVx8Ow6lNe3pi1gWuI//ziHfaUTBrKt6x8) - The number will be found in the *third group*.

Also works with .NET by [getting around the possessive quantifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537513/emulating-possessive-quantifiers) using [atomic groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) ([C# demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E%28%3F%3A.%28%3F%3D.*%5Cn%28%28%3F%3E%5C1%3F%29.%29%29%29*%3F%28%3F%3DSize%29%28%3F%3A%5Cw%5CB%28%3F%3D.*%5Cn%28%3F%3E%5C1%3F%29%28%28%3F%3E%5C2%3F%29%5CD%29%29%29*.*%5Cn%28%3F%3E%5C1%3F%5C2%3F%29%28%3F%3C!%5B%5Cd.%5D%29%28%5B%5Cd.%5D%2B%29&i=Property%20Size%0D%0AJerusale811.00%0D%0A%0D%0ASize%0D%0A811.00%0D%0A%0D%0AProperty%20Size%0D%0AJerusalem%20811.00%0D%0A%0D%0AProperty%20Size%0D%0AJerusalem%20%20811.00%0D%0A%0D%0AProperty%20Size%0D%0AJerusalem%20%20%20811.00%0D%0A%0D%0AProperty%20Size%0D%0AJerusalem%20%20%20%20811.00%0D%0A&o=m)).
In Notepad++ `([\d.]+)` can be [replaced with `\K[\d.]+`](https://regex101.com/r/8ICMXy/6) to [reset before](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) and finding the numbers.

---

More about *how it works* can further be found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74511458/5527985) about *matching a letter below another*.

Comment: this seems much like what the question is asking

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to count the index of 'Size' within the first header row of the output and then use that information to extract the value under 'Size':

```
(?<=(\w\s){1}?)(\d+.\d+)
```

In the example you provided, 'Size' is the second attribute in the row, so there is one word and a space preceding the value you desire (\w\s){1}, we also know that the value is a decimal (\d+.\d+).
If there were 3 attributes, you would replace the 1 with a 2...

**Note:** this solution assumes that every value under each attribute is a single word.

Comment: I guess you could shorten this a bit ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/h0sDWm/1)). Using `{1}` is afaik always redundant and can be spared (I could not imagine any case at least).

Comment: @bobblebubble you do notice that your regex(together with the regex of the solution) does not take into account the value under the word `size` but rather only picks the digits which are preceded by a word. eg if you had another row of data with digits, those digits will be picked if preceded by a word and space.

Comment: @onyambu Have you tried [my demo? e.g. with `foo` above](https://regex101.com/r/5d97Iq/1) It is for extracting the number below the specified word above. It's a "vertical" match, which is the challenge :)